# excel vba, userforms and events: modeless user form that can accept events

Tags: excel, automation, excel-2010, userform, vba

My Excel book contains a user form called `myUserForm`. 
I want to open it, fill it with data and programmatically press its button.
TextBoxes where I input the data have BeforeUpdate and AfterUpdate handlers.

If I call `Call UserForm2.Show`, these events will run, but I seem to be unable to unload the form (calling `Call UserForm2.Show` pauses the execution of excel marco until I manually close it).

If I call don't `Call UserForm2.Show` (or call it in Modeless mode), data population is fine, but Excel BeforeUpdate and AfterUpdate handlers are ignored.

Sample code:

In module:

```
Public Function s(ByVal newValue As String) As String
    'Call UserForm2.Show
    UserForm2.TextBox1.Value = newValue
    UserForm2.Repaint
    s = UserForm2.TextBox1.Value
    UserForm2.Button1_Click
End Function


Public Function s2() As String
    s2 = s("newValue")
End Function
```

In user form:

```
Public Sub Button1_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Public Sub TextBox1_AfterUpdate()
    TextBox1.Value = TextBox1.Value + "y"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to open a form fill it with data then close it with no user interaction? Why bother opening the form at all.

Other than that just move the unload me code to the end of the form load event, or the form activat event... Although this might not work, it worth a try, sorry can't test as not on PC.